# ssl module in python is not available Windows 7

Tags: python, ssl

I have Python 3.7.1 installed on Windows 7 from www.python.org.
When I want to "pip install pylab" I receive the following message:
"pip is configured with locations that require tls/ssl however the ssl module in python is not available".
Please help me to overcome this problem.
Many thanks

Comment: What are the contents of the PATH variable? Probably it’s missing a path here.

Comment: Not sure where the PATH variable should be.

Comment: Open a command window and execute ‘set PATH’ (without the quotes). Post the contents.

Comment: Path=C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Jav
a\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Sy
stem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
PATHEXT=.COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

Comment: I had the same problem installing Annaconda 3.7.1 on Windows 10, and had selected the "Add to Path" option during installation.   @Bhaargavi Agrawal's solution below worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

According to your comment with the PATH variable you are missing the right entries to this so it cannot find the libraries and so on.

If you reinstall python in the first screen you have an option ‘Add Python x.x.x to PATH’ enable this option and then retry what you did.

Comment: One more question if you don't mind. Now when I "pip install pylab" then I got the red message: "could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pylab (from versions:) No matching distribution found for pylab". Do I have to install matplotlib first or is there any other way to get pylab? Many thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use pylab? It was part of Matplotlib but is deprecated for some time already.

Answer (score 5):

I also had the same problem. But solved it by just adding path variables in evt variables 
So check for the following paths 
1. Anaconda root 
2. Anaconda/Scripts
3. Anaconda/Library/bin
the 3rd one was not added and after adding all these evt variables do restart your PC. and the error will be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

What worked for me is:
    `conda activate` in command prompt **and then use pip**

Comment: how is it relevant ? the original post did not mention anything related to conda

Comment: @LoneWanderer, this **works**! Activating `conda` did enable `pip` to work and download the missing `whl` file dependencies on Windows while installing the `whl` I needed. Usage (from `condabin` folder: `activate.bat`) then from the `python.exe` folder `python.exe -m pip install <package>`. This worked **without** me having to pollute my machines' `path`.

Answer (score 0):

Activating conda (from condabin folder: activate.bat)  and  then from the python.exe folder "python.exe -m pip install siphon"

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue because of corporate firewall settings.

If you are on windows go to "Internet Properties" ---> "Connection" ---> "LAN Settings" and check the address (if it is a wpad.dat file, download it and look for "ProxyPort" and "ProxyServer").

Then try :

pip --proxy http://*user*:*password*@*ProxyServer*:*ProxyPort* install *module*