# Error while importing numpy on Eclipse with PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, git, numpy

I'm trying to import numpy on Eclipse with PyDev, and I got this:

```
ImportError: 
Importing the multiarray numpy extension module failed.  Most
likely you are trying to import a failed build of numpy.
If you're working with a numpy git repo, try git clean -xdf (removes all
files not under version control).  Otherwise reinstall numpy.
```

I have already reinstalled Eclipse and the libraries of Anaconda, I installed Eclipse on another laptop of the same way a month ago and I didn't get this Error, I think the problem is caused by the new version of Eclipse, does anyone have the same problem?

I'm using Python 3.7

I have tried to run `git clean -xdf`, but I do not know where should I run it.

UPDATE: 
I've tried to reinstall numpy, I've uninstalled successfully, but when I try to install it again, i got this error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/numpy/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
FINISHED
```

UPDATE: My problem got solved thanks to one comment of below, it can be patched by doing that, but acording to Ananconda, that box should not be marked, so I guess it must be another way of solving the numpy import error in a more appropriate way.

Comment: Did you do a web search for `however the ssl module in Python is not available.` (plus the operating system you use: `Windows`, `Linux` or `macOS`)?

Comment: yeah, but nothing solve my problem :(

Comment: What operating system are you using and what exactly did you try to solve the SSL problem?

Comment: I'm using Windows 64 bits and I don't know what should I do to solve the SSL problem, when I search for a solution, I don't get a clarifying one. I'm 100% sure that the problem is related to the newest version of eclipse, not of the SSL

Comment: According to the error message the SSL issue is not related to Eclipse. Here is a question with the same error message and an answer on how to fix the SSL problem on Windows: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53137700/6505250

Comment: Yeah, I solve my problem!! Thank you so much, but that way of solving it is not the true solution, marking that "box" is not recommended by anaconda, so I guess the problem is still there, but it can be "patched" by doing that.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use numpy on Python 2.7.
Install Python 2.7 and pip install numpy on it.
There might be some distribution issues or compatibility issues of numpy with Python 3.7